# Find Dates on Merge Columns with other data

Tags: google-sheets

We have this tool that extracts raw data, the problem I have is that the date only appears on the heading (merge columns).

Dates from column AH are manually inputted since I am having trouble how to find the date since it was merge and if I extract a monthly raw data the date are always per heading. Sometimes 2 same dates will appear on the heading and some only consist 2 users or less.

```
September 1
User1
User2
User3 
September 2
User1
User2
User3
September 2
User4
User5
```

[image]

Comment: share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output

Comment: Whenever possible, try to include a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that reproduces the issue. You can also include the expected behavior, the actual behavior, and how they differ, that would be helpful as well. Please visit [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to have some tips on how to write a question, so the community will be able to help you out in a better way.

Answer (score 1):

### Edited

It seems like you just need to get the most recent date in `column A` whenever you have a cell that begins with the string `User`.

In that case, I think this would work. It's not a spill array, so you'd have to drag it down, but it would capture the latest date in column A for any user rows.

```
=if(left(A2,4)="User",Max(A$1:A1),if(isdate(A2),A2,""))
```

Comment: A2 is just for the first date, but when I extracted the whole month raw data some dates are on A48, A92, etc (random rows).

Comment: @user19998204 got it. I overlooked that. I presume you don't care if it doesn't do a spill range array.